# HttpWebRequest pass parameters to WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I have a webpage that need to pass data to web Service (SMS) and I tried to use `WebRequest` to do this work but when I use this class the following error appears:

```
Cannot close stream until all bytes are written
```

in the line after this line :

```
stOut.WriteLine(strNewValue,number,text);
```

What is the problem? I tried to use `Flush()` but didn't work either

```
public class SendSms
{
    public SendSms(string number, string text)
    {
         string strNewValue;
         string strResponse;

         HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.buymessage.com/ostazSms/send.php");          

         req.Method = "POST";
         req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
         strNewValue = "usr=****&pwd=*****&to={0}&msg={1}"; 
         req.ContentLength = strNewValue.Length;

         using(StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter (req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Unicode))
         {
             stOut.WriteLine(strNewValue,number,text);
         }

        StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        strResponse = stIn.ReadToEnd();
        stIn.Close();  
    }
}
```

Comment: is it a .net/WDSL webservice? It woudl probably be easier to create a Web reference or service reference and let it handle the http interaction. as for your approach, have you tried flushing the stream after the write?

Comment: @FrankThomas thanks for reply no it's not .net webservice

Comment: webservice site in php ?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you call `WriteLine`, which probably doesn't send all the data.

Here is a snippet that encodes the post data and sends it all:

```
string strNewValue = string.Format("usr=****&pwd=*****&to={0}&msg={1}", "A", "B");
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (strNewValue);
req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

using (Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream ()) {
    dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}
```

Comment: but how i will add parameters into strNewValues ?

Comment: can i use string.format on strNewValues and add values then use the string in byteArray[]

Comment: Perform the string format first so you have your final string before you convert it into a `byteArray`.

Comment: thakyou so much no error is appear but the data is didnot pass to webservice .... can you help me in this :(

Comment: What information did you get back in the response? I would expect an HTTP response code that will help identify the issue.

Comment: in response string i get only "4" that mean some parameter is missing

Comment: i just figure that number 4 mean there is no parameter passed some thing is wrong with pass

Comment: Yes the error code is custom so you might have to ask the service provider what their error codes mean.